# What are the relevant classes / frameworks when I want to write / read stuff to / from disk?

Tags: iphone

Which classes / frameworks must I look at? I don't want to use 3rd party libs, so just plain old, boring default solutions to read / write text files and stuff like that... Is there something like a File IO framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only know 2 ways to read/write to the disk in iphone:

1/ NSUserDefaults: really restricted to some data type only. Look at it here:

[A tutorial on NSUserDefault](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSUserDefaults)

[NSUserDefault Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

2/ NSCoder: you will encode your data and save it to hard disk then you can initWithCoder to get data back. Look at here:

[A good article to begin with](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000084.php)

[NSCoder Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSCoder_Class/Reference/NSCoder.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000293-3497)

[Archive and Serialization](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html)

Just read again that you want to do a text file, so NSFileHandle is also a good choice for you, you can look at here.

3/ NSFileHandle.

[There is a FILE IO part here](http://www.int.gu.edu.au/teaching/2501ICT/archive/gstutorial/en/ch09.html)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a framework.  You can just good old fashioned POSIX calls `open`, `read`, `write`, and all their friends work just as you would suspect.  If you want to move up a level you can use use NSFileHandle to have a Cocoa level interface that is a bit more Objective-C flavored.